# `dask.bag` JSONDecodeError when reading multiline json arrays

Tags: python, json, dask

When using `dask.bag` to read json files I get a `JSONDecodeError` when the json in the file is multiline.

```
import json
import dask.bag as db

db.read_text('single-line.json').map(json.loads).compute()
[[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]]    

db.read_text('multi-line.json').map(json.loads).compute()
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

Here are the example files look like:

Single-line

```
[{"a": "b"}, {"c": "d"}]
```

Multi-line

```
[
    {"a": "b"},
    {"c": "d"}
]
```

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing?

Also worth noting that I can read the multi-line file using just the standard lib

```
with open('multi-line.json') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print(json.loads(data))

[{'a': 'b'}, {'c': 'd'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The read_text function interprets every line of your file as a separate element.  So the elements of your bag look like the following:

```
['[', '{"a": "b"}', '{"c": "d"}', ']']
```

Calling json.loads on some of these elements will fail.  I suspect that you would have a better time if your data was JSON-line delimited.  If you have many json files like this then you could also parallelize with dask.delayed.